# Irrationality of powers of $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, real-analysis

Everyone knows that $\pi$ is an irrational number, and one can refer to this [page](https://planetmath.org/PiAndPi2AreIrrational) for the proof that $\pi^{2}$ is also irrational.

What about the highers powers of $\pi$, meaning is $\pi^{n}$ irrational for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or does there exists a $m \in \mathbb{N}$ when $\pi^{m}$ is rational.

Comment: Not only does everyone know that $\pi$ is irrational,
but everyone also knows that $\pi$ is transcendental :-)

Comment: @Robin Chapman: Ok. Agreed. Ivan Niven's proof is awesome for the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to a proof of transcendentality for completeness?

Comment: The sketch of it at least: if $\pi$ were algebraic, Lindemann-Weierstrass would imply $\exp(2\pi i)$ is transcendental (proving e is transcendental is another story)... and you can fill in the rest.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What Robin hinted at:

If $\pi^{n}$ was rational, then $\pi$ would not be transcendental, as it would be the root of $ax^{n}-b = 0$ for some integers $a,b$.

Comment: @Moron: Ok, then if thats the case then why have they proved the seperate case of $\pi^{2}$ being irrational at planet math. They could have used your argument.

Comment: @Chandru: No idea. Perhaps they have it there for historical reasons.

Comment: There's a (relatively) simple proof that just happens to work
for $\pi^2$ (and from which the $\pi$ case is an immediate
corollary).

Comment: 1768 pi irrational, 1882 pi transcendental.  proving irrationality is easier than proving transcendence. using the fact that pi is transcendantal seems to be overkill (in my interpretation of OP's question)

Comment: @yoyo: The question was, is $\pi^m$ rational for some integer $m \gt 0$. The answer is no. How does it matter how hard it is prove that?

Comment: By the same method, ${\pi}^r$ is irrational (even transcendental) for all nonzero rational $r.$ A possibly interesting question (which may have an easy answer -- I haven't given it any thought yet) is whether there exists an irrational algebraic real number $x$ such that ${\pi}^x$ is rational, and also whether there exists an explicit irrational algebraic number $y$ (i.e. can be expressed using radicals) such that ${\pi}^y$ is irrational.

Comment: In my 2nd question, what I actually meant (but didn't think about until it was too late to edit my comment) is that can such a number $y$ can be explicitly exhibited, as opposed to simply proved to exist by some non-constructive method.