# Alternative Proof of Infinitely Many Primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, alternative-proof

I've seen Euclid's proof of infinitely many primes, what are other approaches to proving there are infinitely many primes?

Comment: I googled "infinitely many primes" and found [this](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/infinite/)

Comment: @BalarkaSen Is that a product over primes? How did the summation turn into that?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n = \prod_p \left ( 1 - \frac1p \right )^{-1}$$ The harmonic series diverges. 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} = \pi^2/6 = \prod_p \left ( 1 - \frac1{p^2} \right)^{-1}$$ $\pi^2$ is irrational. Plus, if you forgive me the cheek $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} = \prod_p \left ( 1 - \frac1{p^3}\right)^{-1}$$ $\zeta(3)$ is irrational too.

Comment: @user45572 See [Euler product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product)

Comment: @BalarkaSen I know pi is irrational, why does that imply you can write it as a product over primes?

Comment: @user45572 Have you seen that link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\prod_k \frac 1 {1-p_k^{-2}}=\sum_n n^{-2}=\zeta(2)=\frac {\pi^2}6,$$
and $\pi^2$ is irrational ([from my favorite math resource](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2285/19341)) so we need infinitely many primes...

Answer (score 6):

Here's another proof.I thought of it a while ago, and posted it as an answer to a mathoverflow question, but I don't imagine I was the first to think of it. The idea is not to rely on the fact that $\pi$ is irrational. Let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of primes. We have 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4}} = \frac{\pi^{4}}{90}.$ The first equation yields, $\prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}}\frac{p^{2}}{p^{2}-1} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$ and the second leads to $\prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}}\frac{p^{4}}{p^{4}-1} = \frac{\pi^{4}}{90}.$ If we square the first of the last two equations and divide by the second, we obtain $\prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}}\frac{p^{2}+1}{p^{2}-1} = \frac{5}{2}.$ If $\mathcal{P}$ was finite, the left hand expression would be a rational number whose numerator was not divisible by $3$, but whose denominator was divisible by $3$ (because $p^{2}+1 \equiv 2$ (mod $3$) for every prime other than $3$, and $p^{2}-1$ is divisible by $3$ for every prime other than $3$). However, no such rational number could be equal to $\frac{5}{2},$ a contradiction.

Comment: (+1)This is one fun proof! Interestingly, irrationality of $\pi$ gives much stronger result than infinitude of primes $$\frac{\pi}{4} = \sum_{n= 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} = \prod_{p \equiv 1(4)} \frac{p}{p-1} \cdot \prod_{p \equiv 3(4)} \frac{p}{p+1}$$ Thus at least one of the class $1\pmod{4}$ or $3\pmod{4}$ contains infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 5):

The prime harmonic series $\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 5 + \ldots$ [diverges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes).

Comment: Isn't the fact that it diverges dependent on there being infinitely many primes in the first place? How else could the discussion of divergence even occur otherwise?

Comment: @Axoren: This is done formally by considering the sum of the reciprocals of all primes less than n for each n. These sums define a sequence (which would eventually be constant if there were finitely many primes), and you can show that the n-th sum is bounded below by $\log\log n - (\text{constant})$ where the constant is independent of n. Hence these sums tend to infinity (and, by definition, the corresponding series diverges).

Answer (score 5):

Here is one of my favorites: $f(n) = 2^{2^{n}}+2^{2^{n-1}}+1, n \in \mathbb{N}$ has $n$ different prime factors. Prove by induction.

Comment: I think $2^{2^{n}}-1$ has the same property ( ie, at least $n$ different prime factors).

Answer (score 1):

There is a topological proof: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes

Apart from that there are almost infinitely many proofs..

Comment: Could you explain the topological proof? I find the Wiki article difficult to parse...

Comment: @user45572 Explanation: Declare each arithmetic sequence to be "closed", and extend this terminology to finite unions.  Verify that the complement of a finite set is *not* closed.  Verify that the complement of $\{\pm 1\}$ is the union of arithmetic sequences whose ratios are exactly the prime numbers (by prime factorization).  Since it's cofinite, this must be an infinite union, QED.

Comment: Note that it's not really a topological proof at all.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).  Shows not only infinitely many primes, but infinitely many primes in each (nontrivial) residue class in any modulus.  Proof relies on analytic properties of Dirichlet series.