# showing $\pi^r$ is irrational

Tags: calculus, number-theory, irrational-numbers

I want to show $\pi^r$ is irrational, where $r\in \mathbb{Q}-{0}$

Recently, I learn some proof of $e^{r}$ where $r\in \mathbb{Q}-{0}$ is irrational.

It was done by setting
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{n!} 
\end{align}
with some manipulation of calculus.

Employing similar approach can we do this for $\pi^r$?

If you know some references regarding this please make some comments!

Of course any other approach is welcomed!

Comment: See this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284/irrationality-of-powers-of-pi), for integral powers. It also works for rational powers of $\pi$.

Comment: Proving that $\pi$ is transcendental immediately takes care of this, and I suspect proof of transcendence will be no less difficult than what you're attempting to show.

Comment: The traditional argument shows $\pi^2$ is irrational.  For the rest, I'd think it was best to just prove transendence.

Comment: This article might be relevant: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788

Answer (score 2):

If $r=\frac{p}{q}$, was rational, where $p,q$ integers, i.e.,
$$
\pi^{p/q}=\frac{m}{n}, \quad\text{for some $m,n\in\mathbb N$,}
$$
then
$$
\pi^p=\frac{m^q}{n^q},
$$
and hence $\pi$ would be satisfy the equation
$$
n^qx^p-m^q=0,
$$ 
and hence $\pi$ would be an algebraic number, but $\pi$ is not algebraic, it is a transcendental number!

Answer (score 1):

The OP is presumably asking if there is a proof that doesn't boil down to proving the transcendentality of $\pi$. A useful reference is ["Irrationality of $\pi$ and $e$"](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~khlee/math2784s10/piande.pdf) by Keith Conrad, which includes proofs that $\pi$ is irrational (Theorem 2.1) and that $e^r$ is irrational for any nonzero rational number $r$ (Theorem 5.1), along with a brief discussion of the difference between the two proofs:

> Although the proofs of Theorems 2.1 and 5.1 are similar in the sense
>   that both used estimates on integrals, the proof of Theorem 2.1 did
>   not show $\pi$ is irrational by exhibiting a sequence of good rational
>   approximations to $\pi$. The proof of Theorem 2.1 was an “integer
>   between $0$ and $1$” proof by contradiction. No good rational
>   approximations to $\pi$ were produced in that proof. It is simply *harder*
>   to get our grips on $\pi$ than it is on powers of $e$.

Remark: I found the Conrad paper through a comment at another MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476939/proving-the-irrationality-of-en).